# Change section name twice (or make a section appear in TOC only, not in text)?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, appendices

I am trying to have a document with TOC:

1 Introduction

2 blabla

3 Conclusion

Bibliography

Appendix 1

I want the Bibliography to start with title "Bibliography" but I do not want the Appendix 1 to start with title "Appendix 1". I just want to include some PDF pages without a title preceeding them. I, however, want both Bibliography and Appendix 1 to have headings specifying whether the page is a part of bibliography or Appendix 1.

Test document is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{appendix}

\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\newpage\stdsection} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\section{Úvod}
blabla


\section{Závěr}
bleble

\newpage

\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
bli
\end{thebibliography}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Appendix 1}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendix 1}
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc
\renewcommand{\refname}{Appendix 1}
\newpage
bla
\includepdf[scale=0.85,pages={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16},pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy},\fancyfoot{}}]{original.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The bibliography looks right: [image]
I would like the heading of page 5 to be "Appendix 1" (see the command `\renewcommand{\refname}{Appendix}` before includepdf), but it is "Bibliography" like this: [image]

I do not understand why `\renewcommand` works for the first time but not for the second.

Alternative way to achieve what I want would be to start a section without it being printed in the actual document but only in the TOC - I have not managed to google how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're using the [babel](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/babel) package, you can't use the "standard LaTeX" method of setting

```
\newnewcommand{\refname}{blabla}
```

Instead, given that you've specified `czech` as the language when loading `babel`, you should include the following command in the preamble:

```
\addto{\captionsczech}{\renewcommand{\refname}{blabla}}
```

(where, of course, "blabla" should be replaced with whatever text string may be appropriate).

Separately, you write that

> I do not understand why `\renewcommand` works for the first time but not for the second.

Actually, it doesn't work the first time either! It just doesn't do anything, given that you're using `babel`. But, as the default name of the bibliography section is already `Bibliography`, the error doesn't become apparent.

Comment: Hm, that (`\addto{\captionsczech}{\renewcommand{\refname}{blabla}}`) does not help. 

 `\renewcommand` works for the first time, the default Czech name for "Bibliography" is "Reference". 

Have you tried to compile the document? If so, maybe there is something specific to my setup (it is Texlive 2011 on Ubuntu 12.04 as fat as I can tell, and I am using pdflatex).

Comment: I updated the question with screenshots of the actual rendering.

Comment: @sup: Thanks for the additional information. The problem you're running into, when you issue the second `\renewcommand\refname` instruction, is that this instruction won't affect the header line until you actually issue a section-level command, as would be generated by a `\begin{thebibliography}{99}` macro. Without this additional command, the header line info remains determined by the most recent section-level command, at which time the header info was "Bibliography". The remedy is simple: Instead of the new `\renewcommand{\refname}`, type `\fancyhead[L]{\MakeUppercase{\appendixtocname}}`.

Comment: I had to put in a `\newpage` after `\end{thebibliography}` but with that it works, so thanks!

Comment: @sup: I'm glad you were able to work out that you needed an additional `\newpage` command before issuing the instruction `\fancyhead[L]{\MakeUppercase{\appendixtocname}}`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to define some new page styles:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{appendix}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\fancypagestyle{normal}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
}
\fancypagestyle{appendix}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyhead[L]{Appendix 1}
}

\let\stdsection\section
\renewcommand\section{\newpage\stdsection} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\pagestyle{normal}




\section{Úvod}
blabla


\section{Závěr}
bleble

\newpage

\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
bli
\end{thebibliography}

\newpage
\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Appendix 1}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendix 1}
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc
\renewcommand{\refname}{Appendix 1}

\pagestyle{appendix}

bla

\shorthandoff{-}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{appendix}},scale=0.85]{original.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Notice the `\shorhandoff` command necessary to be able to use `pages=-`, and the `\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}` for adjusting the head height.

Comment: Thanks for the `\shorhandoff`, I felt stupid to list all the pages to include but it kept giving back errors when using dash. (I actually use `\setlength` but I excluded it from the example file, but thanks anyway.) I guess your solution would work too, but the above one is working already, thanks for replying anyway.